# Issue with newid() after dropping table constraints using t-sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a scenario where I have to drop primary key on a existing table and then insert a record into it. The table has a column called GUID as shown below

```
Create Table TEST_TABLE_VALUE (
        TEST_TABLE_ID int Identity(1,1),
        TEST_TABLE_VALUE int,                       
        GUID uniqueidentifier Not Null  Default newid(),
        Primary Key (TEST_TABLE_ID, TEST_TABLE_VALUE)
)
```

Dropped the constraints using below code

```
Declare @TableName nvarchar(100)
Declare @TableId int
Declare @ConstraintName varchar(120)
Declare @IndexName varchar(120)
Declare @Command varchar(256)

Set @TableName = 'TEST_TABLE_VALUE'
Select @TableId = id From sysobjects Where [type]='U' and [name]=@TableName

  Declare ConstraintDropCursor Cursor Local Fast_Forward
  For Select name from sysobjects where (type='K' Or type='D' or type='F' or type='C') and parent_obj = @TableId
  For Read Only
     Open ConstraintDropCursor
       Fetch Next From ConstraintDropCursor Into @ConstraintName
         While @@Fetch_Status != -1
           Begin
             Set @Command = 'Alter Table dbo.' + @TableName + ' Drop Constraint ' + @ConstraintName
             exec(@Command)
             Fetch Next From ConstraintDropCursor Into @ConstraintName
           End
     Close ConstraintDropCursor
     DeAllocate ConstraintDropCursor
```

After dropping the constraints when I tried to insert data into the table

```
Insert Into TEST_TABLE_VALUE (TEST_TABLE_VALUE) Values(1)
```

but got the below error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'GUID', table 'CustApp1.dbo.TEST_TABLE_VALUE1'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Generally thinking you should be dropping constraints is a clue that you are doing something wrong. The constraints are there fo ra reason.

Comment: @HLGEM, I'm dropping constraints only to re-add them with proper name. In the above case I forgot to add GUID default constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dropped the default for GUID column and it is not nullable column.Thus it is causing the issue. In case you want to insert lots of data and do not want constraint for maybe perf reasons. Then atleast do not drop the defaults for not nullable columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you drop the default constraint you end up with

```
Create Table TEST_TABLE_VALUE ( 
        TEST_TABLE_ID int Identity(1,1), 
        TEST_TABLE_VALUE int,                        
        GUID uniqueidentifier Not Null, 
        Primary Key (TEST_TABLE_ID, TEST_TABLE_VALUE) 
)
```

so if you wish to continue down this path you either have to provide a value for the GUID column

or also do

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE_VALUE ALTER COLUMN GUID uniqueidentifier NULL
```

to allow nulls.